# Create a view of nodes based on user record

Tags: views, entities, users

In Drupal 7, I have a Content Type, let's call it **fruit**. I have added an entity reference field to fruit to the user record. I want to create a view that lists all the fruit, but puts a mark next to those that have been ticked on their user record.

I am unable to work out how to do this, principally because I can't see how to add a Relationship to the user record.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, you're wanting to mark fruit nodes that have an user entity reference to the current user looking at the view?

Comment: The entity reference to the fruit nodes is on the User profile. But yes, I want to mark the fruit nodes for the current user. Thinking about it, perhaps adding the entity reference to the user profile wasn't be best approach...

Comment: Hmm, that's the opposite of how read the question, but no matter. You can reference both sides of the relationship. I wrote an answer that discusses the heart of relationship referencing.

Answer (score 0):

For entity reference fields there are 2 types of relationships added to views: a *Referenced entity* and a *Referencing entity*.

- *Referenced entity* is used for a reference *from the base table* (e.g. A user view that references a fruit node).
- *Referencing entity* is used for a reference *to the base table* (e.g. a fruit node view that references a user)

In your case, it's *Referencing entity* that you want.

Create a node view and a *Entity Reference: Referencing entity* relationship (the description should read *A bridge to the User entity that is referencing Content via field_FRUIT_NODE_REF*) that refers to your fruit node reference.

That should handle the data/reference part. What remains is aggregation/filtering (e.g. there will duplicates if fruit node references aren't distinct for each user) and display (e.g. how to display marking a fruit node referencing a current user).

Depending on your needs, you might need a custom field/template since there is a limit of what you can do with field basic rewriting and default user contextual filters.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this partly solves my problem. The issue is that the current user profile isn't one of the suggestions that comes up for Referencing entity in Views - so I need to work out how to get around that.